# Can I enable Redshift cross region snapshot copy through cloudformation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, aws-cloudformation

[Redshift CFN resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-redshift-cluster.html#cfn-redshift-cluster-destinationregion) `AWS::Redshift::Cluster` has two properties for configuring cross region snapshot copy: `DestinationRegion` and `SnapshotCopyGrantName`. But after creating the stack with those parameters I see the cross region snapshot copy is still disabled. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not yet supported, but its **already on the roadmap**: [AWS::Redshift::SnapshotConfiguration](https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/cloudformation-coverage-roadmap/issues/870).

For now you would have to use [custom resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html) in the form of a lambda function which would use AWS SDK's [enable_snapshot_copy](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/redshift.html#Redshift.Client.enable_snapshot_copy) to enable the snapshot copies. You could also use [AWSUtility::CloudFormation::CommandRunner](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudformation-commandrunner-stack/) to enable that with AWS CLI.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to use intrinsic functions in the CommandRunner command like Ref? I couldn't find any example or in the doc.

Comment: @Nisman You can use Sub function create commands referencing your existing resources or parameters.